# Flickering of bitmap on canvas in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

How to avoid image flickering when drawing on canvas.
Below code keep on running for images.The next image comes sliding from top but the previous image keep on flickering at back.I just want the previous image to become static.

```
void drawscreen()
{
    SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
    try
    {
        Backgroundcanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        if (Backgroundcanvas != null)
        {
            if (top == true)
            { slide_from_top(); }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (Backgroundcanvas != null)
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(Backgroundcanvas);
    }

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateDisplay);
    if (mVisible && count)
    {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateDisplay, interval);
        count = false;
    }
    else
    {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateDisplay, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting same problem,  **image flickering when drawing on canvas** .

What I have done is making my worker thread(Not UI Thread) **sleep for 10mlsec** every time after using canvas drawing, and this time flickering is gone,

You can try this trick...

Comment: @Swarnendu-Thanks,will try this

Answer (score 0):

Clear canvas after each thread ends.

Just call `Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK),` or whatever color you want to clear your Canvas with.

Comment: @syed-Thanks for reply.I tried but its not working.the screen become black for some time and then the image comes from top with previous image blinking at the back

Comment: @Ruhi Did u find the solution? I am having the same problem when clearing canvas. A black blink occurs when image changes